# react-native-router-flux The prop is marked as required, but its value is 'undefined'

Tags: redux, react-native-router-flux

This is a react native project.
I am using Redux and react-native-router-flux.

My error is this
The prop 'Layout' is marked as required in 'Account', but its value is 'undefined'

In my routes codes, I have a Scene like this, definitely passing the 'Layout' in the element.

```
<Scene
        key="account"
        title="Account"
        icon={({focused}) => (<Icon name="heart-outline" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={[{ color: focused ? activeColor : inactiveColor }, { height: 30, width: 30 }]} />)}
        navBar={() => <MyHeader onLeftPressed={Actions.pop} onRightPressed={Actions.addcards} text="Account" back={false} />}
        {...DefaultProps.navbarProps} Layout={AccountComponent}
        component={AccountContainer}>
    </Scene>
```

Of course I have included the file

```
import AccountComponent from '../components/Account';
```

And here is part of 'AccountContainer' code

```
const Account = ({
  Layout,
  locale
}) => (
  <AccountComponent 
    locale={locale} 
  />
);
```

Can I pass the AccountComponent through the 'Layout' instead of explicitly writing it in the above code? But it seems that the 'Layout' is undefined

One more info is that when I switch page to Account, i use this code to switch page.

```
_gotoAccount() {
Actions.replace('account');
```

}

I don't know if this replace action cleared the prop / changed something?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Same error a year later

Answer (score 0):

To future people with this issue: Make sure if you have keys on your scenes, that the keys are unique.

I had two Scenes with the same key, spent many hours on a silly issue.